# How to load compressed .dds images as collada textures?

Tags: webgl, three.js

Do you have any idea how could I use compressed .dds images as collada textures?

Which part of the library should be updated to do this?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**DDS**

Three.js can already read in dds files.

just call THREE.ImageUtils.loadCompressedTexture:

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/extras/ImageUtils.js#L39

**Collada**

This line needs to be updated to detect wether the the file is a dds file or a normal image and use the corresponding method to read that file.

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/loaders/ColladaLoader.js#L3116

Comment: Wohoo, works! That's what I was looking for! Thank you so much!

Comment: What happened to this? ImageUtils.js doesn't seem to be included anymore.