# Three.js Colladaloader DDS textures

Tags: three.js, collada

I have a problem with the colladaloader. I need to load dds textures, but the colladaloader want to load images. In the browser console I get the following message:

Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type image/vnd.ms-dds

Is it possible to change something in the colladaloader.js to load dds or what can I do the solve that problem?

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use THREE.ImageUtils.loadCompressedTexture

Check this out if you haven't already...

[How to load compressed .dds images as collada textures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737400/how-to-load-compressed-dds-images-as-collada-textures)

Comment: I already checked this link out, but in my Collada file I have dds textures and I need to load the collada file with the dds textures and when I edit the colladaloader file with THree.ImageUtils.loadCompressedTexture, I get the following warning:
"drawElements: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering or is not 'texture complete'. Or the texture is Float or Half Float type with linear filtering while OES_float_linear or OES_half_float_linear extension is not enabled."

The textures are loading, but not 100% right.

Comment: I could be wrong but i think that just means you want your texture dimensions to be a power of 2 ratio. So like 320x640, 512x1024 etc.
What are you using to do your modeling and texturing?

Comment: When I'm right the model and textures are made with blender, but I don't know exactly because I got the models from another person.

Comment: id open up the UV editor in blender and check out the texture dimensions. I think you just need the proper ratio especially if they are loading but not wrapped properly.

Comment: Ok thanks I will look that tomorrow, but one additional question what is a proper ratio?

Comment: Well if I'm reading your error correctly you want one dimension to equal the other if added to itself. 320+320 = 640 so power of 2 would be 320x640. Post back (accept this as answer) and let us know if that was it.